# Why when I define the variable I defined in the for loop as global, it only writes once on the serial monitor?

Tags: c++, arduino

as you can see below, I have defined the variable that I need to define in the for loop global, and this time the for loop only worked once, even though it was inside the void loop. Could you tell me why?

```
char i = 'A';

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    for ( ; i <= 'Z'; i++)
        Serial.print(i);
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: After the first time throught the loop, `i` is `[` (which is `'Z' + 1`). You need to reset it each time: `for (i = 'A' ; i <= 'Z'; i++)`

Comment: Maybe just define `i` inside `void loop()`.

Comment: So when I define the variable as global, why does it use it only once?

Comment: @BeratDurmus The variable simply keeps it's value. Why should it be reset to anything?

Comment: Sorry sir I'm just beginner on the programming and I just want to know the answer to this, why does the output not loop even though I defined the variable outside of void loop? There is no problem in the code.

Comment: @BeratDurmus there **is** problem that it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @BeratDurmus *Sorry sir I'm just beginner on the programming* -- Avoid global variables as much as possible.  If you heed that advice, you would never come across the issue you're having now with the loop.  Also, if someone were to just look at the `void loop()` function you wrote, they would have no idea what `i` starts out with, unless they go through your entire source code to figure out what it actually is.  That's why it would have been much better if `i` were local, so everyone knows what it is at the start of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `i` is a global variable, it's value persists through each call to `loop()`.

First time `loop()` is called:

```
void loop() {
    // i == 'A', it's initial value
    for ( ; i <= 'Z'; i++)
        Serial.print(i);
    // Now, i == '[' because of i++ in the loop
    delay(500);
}
```

Second time `loop()` is called:

```
void loop() {
    // i == '[', it's value from before, when loop finished the first time
    for ( ; i <= 'Z'; i++)
        Serial.print(i);
    // i == '[' because the loop is not entered because `[` is not lte `Z`
    delay(500);
}
```

And `i` stays equal to `'['` since it does not get reset anywhere. You can reset it in the loop each time:

```
for (i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
```

In your code, there is no reason I can see to make `i` global, so you can just declare it locally:

```
for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
```